# Why PHP Session Destroyed?

Tags: lighttpd, php

I have this php code,

```
<?php

session_start();
Print_r($_SESSION);
$_SESSION['value'] = 1;
Print_r($_SESSION);

?>
```

Why it Prints following, everytime when I refreshes the page..

```
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [value] => 1
)
```

It should Print,

```
Array
(
    [value] => 1
)
Array
(
    [value] => 1
)
```

I am using `lighttpd` as `http` Server on Fedora 14.

Comment: it should not...and it wont...but first time you will always get the first result.. second time the next one

Comment: I know but everytime I am getting the first result,,,

Comment: Have you checked your session ini settings?

Comment: ya and is <?php the first line of program??? no space before it... make sure of that

Comment: Have you changed `session.save_path`? What does `session_save_path()` return, and is the server allowed to write to it?

Comment: What particular I should have to check in php.ini?

Comment: It work for me with no problem. It's something wrong with your php.ini

Comment: `session_save_path()` returning `/var/lib/php/session`

Comment: I think these would be your main ones to look for:  
`session.use_cookies = 1` `session.cookie_path = /`

Comment: @Ryan Naddy: Both are correct as you mentioned.

Comment: `lighttpd` is closing tcp connection after every request, is this the reason?

Comment: shouldn't be, I read that running `chown -R root:lighttpd /var/lib/php/` fixed the problem. http://www.masdeni.com/archives/6-Lighttpd-+-PHP-Session-Problem.html

Comment: @Ryan Naddy...yes you solved my problem thanks:),,,POST your answer and I will mark as Correct..:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read that running `chown -R root:lighttpd /var/lib/php/` fixed the problem for others that were having the same issue.

Source:
http://masdeni.com/archives/6-Lighttpd-+-PHP-Session-Problem.html

Answer (score 1):

I would test to see if `session_start()` returns `true` (session started), for example:

```
$is_session_started = session_start();
```

If `$is_session_started == false`, then you have 1/2 your answer right there. The other 1/2 will lie in figuring out why it is not starting. Per @Ryan above, check your session ini settings.

If you are using cookies for storing the Session ID, make sure that you call `session_start()` before printing/echoing/returning any other values to the browser.

Comment: Then I would look at the post @ryan-naddy references in his comment above. The session is being created, but it's not persisting.