# PHP session gets destroyed for no reason

Tags: php, session

I developed a web application that allows both entrepreneurs and customers to log in through two different login portals. I developed the application locally, using a XAMPP, i.e. Apache, configuration. There, it worked perfectly.

I am now trying to have it run on a Lighttpd web server which works OK. I'm running into a weird issue. If I use the customer login, everything works fine, the session gets created, and the customer keeps having access to his account data.

When I login through the entrepreneur portal, something strange happens. When I `var_dump()`'d the `$_SESSION` variable, directly after logging in shows me the session object correctly. When pressing F5, or navigating to another page in the portal, the `$_SESSION` variable gets destroyed and `var_dump($_SESSION)` shows an empty array.

I found [Why PHP Session Destroyed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079769/why-php-session-destroyed) that proposes a solution to fix Lighttpd destroying sessions. I assume that is not the problem, as my sessions work at one login portal, while not at the other.

Does anyone have a clue why my session gets destroyed?

This is how I set my session variable:

`$_SESSION["ll_oid"] = $q["id"]`
(where `$q["id"]` is the entrepreneur ID)

And this is how I check it:

```
 $id = $_SESSION["ll_oid"];
 if($id == null) {
 session_destroy();
 header("Location: index.php");
 die();
 }
```

At all pages, `session_start()` is called before any headers are sent.

Comment: show the entrepreneur portal code.

Comment: A session is basically a cookie. And cookies are not valid in other (sub) domains by default, if that is the case. Basically, inspect your cookie data.

Comment: @Xorifelse Entrepreneurs log in at /ondernemers/index.php and get referenced to /ondernemers/panel.php. All pages are in /ondernemers/. Does this still might result into problems?

Comment: @RyanVincent I will check.

Comment: @RyanVincent Page contains no errors

Comment: @cheralathan `session_start();
  require("../Db.class.php");
  $db = new Db();
  $id = $_SESSION["ll_oid"];
  if($id == null) {
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();
  }`

Comment: @user3235949 Not with folders no, but it could make a difference on  `www.domain.nl` and `domain.nl`. Perhaps *Lighttpd* is reffering to your sub domain (www)?

Comment: do one thing die before if condition and check the session variable

Comment: @cheralathan I did. It contains the ll_oid attribute right after login, but is empty after F5.

Comment: @Xorifelse Both www. and non-www. give the same thing